# How do I initialize my admin Class from a "custom django-admin command"?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have functions in my admin Class that I'd like to perform on a regular basis (every 10 minutes). I am trying to use the "custom django-admin commands" solution ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands ) and will use a cron job to run it.

I do have the custom command working with test code, however I am running into a few issues:

- I'm not sure how to initialize the class (I get errors such as "missing 1 required positional argument"). If I skip instantiation I can call the functions explicitly, but then I run into these next two problems.
- I'm used to calling internal Admin class functions using "self.functionname()".   But 'self' doesn't work when called from my custom management command.
- Many of my admin functions use the standard 'request' argument; however I don't have a 'request' from my custom management command.

*These code snippets are paraphrased from the originals.*

**polls/management/commands/performTasks.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question
from polls.admin import QuestionAdmin

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Starts the process.'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        QuestionAdmin.tasks(self, 'YES')

        # The following 2 lines I simply use to prove a successful query:
        myqueryset = Question.objects.filter(author="Tolkien")
        print(myqueryset)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['pub_date', 'question_text']

    def tasks(self, arg1):

        # This does print "YES" so I know the custom management command works.
        print(arg1)

        # again, the following 2 lines I simply use to prove a successful query:
        myqueryset = Question.objects.filter(author="Tolkien")
        print(myqueryset)


        # This next line fails from the Custom management command with:
        # AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'stepOne'
        self.stepOne(self, request, myqueryset)

    def stepOne(self, request, queryset):
    
        result = self.stepTwo(request, queryset)

    def stepTwo(self, request, queryset):
        ''' The actual function performs a logic test and returns True or False. '''

        return True
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

So 3 questions... heavily related:

1. What's the correct way to initialize my admin Class?
2. How do I propagate 'self' through my admin Classes functions?
3. How could I handle the missing 'request' arguments?

Also any comments about the feasibility of using the Custom Management command would be welcome. My goal is to use a complex set of function (that already work from the Admin class) on a regular (every 10 minutes) basis.

Comment: Please *don't*. Just make a separate function, that performs the logic, and *then* use it in both the management command and Django admin.

Comment: There is furthermore not a `request` when you make a managent command because, well..., there is no HTTP request, you simply run a command.

Comment: I am curious as to why `def tasks()`, `stepOne()`, and `stepTwo()` is in your `QuestionsAdmin`. Without knowing what it does I am guessing these functions should either live in your `Question`-model if these are steps taken to one object, or in QuestionManager if it does something to multiple Questions. I think you should check out the docs on [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) or put your business logic in a separate file like `services.py` or `question_logic.py` and reference that from your Command and Admin files as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think my solution has grown more 'organically' rather than 'conscientiously'. So I have now gone a completely different way.
Still... it seems to me that it must be possible to gain access to the class (QuestionAdmin) - if someone knows the actual answer to that I'd like to hear it.